# Async Method not running properly in service mode in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following service defined. The service is supposed to run when the device is booted up. However, the service is successfully started, but it seems on of the method within the `DoBackgroundJob()` method does not get invoked. When I launch the service from the MainActivity and put breakpoints, the all the methods are executed correctly and I get the desired result. Could someone please advise what is wrong here ?

I have wrapped the `DoBackgroundJob()` in a new thread so that the service does not block the UI of the application if it is launched manually. The application is supposed to work in two separate processes.

What I am wondering, is whether an async method like `DoBackgroundJob()` should contain all the methods within it async ? Please help me to solve this issue, as I suspect some methods is not having sufficient to be invoked properly.

```
    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        try
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                dsa = new DataServiceAccess();
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {                     
                    await DoBackgroundJob();
                });
            });

            t.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;

    }

    public void GetGps()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                LocationService locService = new LocationService();
                GpsData = locService.GetLocation();
                a = GpsData.Latitude;
                b = GpsData.Longitude;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });        
    }

    public async Task DoBackgroundJob()
    {
        GetGps();

        try
        {

            ObservableCollection<Trucks> Trucks = new ObservableCollection<Trucks>();
            Trucks truck = new Trucks();
            TrucksService ds = new TrucksService();

            beacon.DetectAvailableTrucks();

            await Task.Delay(100000);

            Trucks = beacon.GetAvailableTrcuks();

            await MatchRequiredTrayBeacon(Truckss);


            await Task.Delay(8000);
            await DoBackgroundJob();


        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {


        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded> ConstructTrucks(ObservableCollection<Trucks> trucksMatch)
    {
        string address = "";

        List<ConfigDataModel> conf = new List<ConfigDataModel>();
        conf =  dsa.GetAllConfigData();

        foreach (var item in conf)
        {
            address = item.address;
        }

        ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded> TrucksLoadedFound = new ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded>();

        foreach (var item in matchedBeacon)
        {

            TrucksLoadedFound.Add(new TrucksLoaded(item.Id, item.Name, address, latitude,
            longitude, DateTime.Now.ToString(), false, item.BatteryLife));

        }

        return TrucksLoadedFound;

    }


    public ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded> MatchTrucks(ObservableCollection<Trucks> foundTrucks)
    {
        TrucksLoaded = new ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded>();

        foundTrucks = new ObservableCollection<Trucks>();

        foundTrucks = HandleTrucks(foundTrucks);

        TrucksLoaded = ConstructTrucks(foundTrucks);

        SavetoLocalDB(TrucksLoaded);

        return TrucksLoaded;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Trucks> CheckMatching(ObservableCollection<Trucks> foundTrucks)
    {
          MatchedTrucks = new ObservableCollection<Trucks>();

          // matching logic implemeted here.. 

     return MatchedTrucks;

    }

    private void SavetoLocalDB(ObservableCollection<TrucksLoaded> TrucksLoaded)
    { 
        foreach (var item in TrucksLoaded)
        {
            dsa.AddTrucksLoaded(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

**Partial Code of Location Service that requires to be run on a main thread**

```
 public void InitLocation()
    {
        if (_locationManager.AllProviders.Contains(LocationManager.NetworkProvider) && _locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider))
        {
            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 2000, 5, this);
        }
```

Comment: I assume this is on Android and you are using XF. Does any of the code used in the service require Xamarin Forms to be initialized (such as `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`)? If so, you will have to init XF manually when the app is not running. It may be that the async code is swallowing the exceptions.

Comment: No, the code is running correctly on debug mode. The suspect is with the await and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You *can not* use `Xamarin.Forms` calls within the `Service`.

- Calling `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` will cause your `Service` to be killed when your service receives the `Intent.ActionBootCompleted` as you do not have a UI and an inited Xamarin.Forms app... Since you have the service returning `StartCommandResult.Sticky` the OS will will continually try to restart your service (on an ever decreasing schedule).

You do not need the double thread in the `OnStartCommand`, just one will do it.

- Only start your worker thread once as `OnStartCommand` can get called multiple times...

I do not know what your `LocationService` method consists of, but again make sure that you are not using Xamarin.Forms calls in it.

- The Android location services, or preferably the Google Fused Location services, will work fine without any Forms calls.

Test your Service startup on `ActionBootCompleted` by using `adb`, depending upon the device/emulator type/API/etc... you can use one of these `adb` cmds:

- `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p UseYourPackageNameHere`
- `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`
- `adb reboot`

#### Example:

Add your boot permissions (manually in the manifest or via an attribute)

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
```

#### Service code:

```
[Service]
public class BootService : Service
{
    const string TAG = "SushiHangover";
    public const string SERVICE = "com.sushihangover.BootService";
    Thread serviceThread;

    public IBinder Binder { get; private set; }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnStartCommand : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        serviceThread = serviceThread ?? new Thread(ServiceRun); // Many ways... use a Task with a cancellation token, etc... 
        if (!serviceThread.IsAlive)
            try
            {
                serviceThread.Start();
            }
            catch (ThreadStateException ex) when (ex.Message == "Thread has already been started.")
            {
                // Xamarin.Android bug: isAlive always returns false, so eat the Start() exception if needed
            }

        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnTrimMemory(TrimMemory level)
    {
        // Stop serviceThread? free resources? ...
        base.OnTrimMemory(level);
    }

    public override void OnLowMemory()
    {
        // Stop serviceThread? free resources? ...
        base.OnLowMemory();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        serviceThread.Abort(); // Handle ThreadAbortException in your thread, cleanup resources if needed...
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnBind");
        Binder = new BootBinder(this);
        return Binder;
    }

    public class BootBinder : Binder
    {
        public BootBinder(BootService service)
        {
            Service = service;
        }

        public BootService Service { get; private set; }
    }

    async void ServiceRun()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) // Handle cancellations...
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"{i} : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

#### BroadcastReceiver code:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]    
public class BootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string TAG = "SushiHangover";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnReceive");
        var serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(BootService));
        context.StartService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

#### Test

Install the app, via a debugging session is fine, as long as you have started the app at least once.

Now trigger the `ActionBootCompleted` intent via the `adb` cmd above.

Monitor `logcat` and you should see (I issued multiple `ActionBootCompleted`):

```
 D SushiHangover: OnReceive
 D SushiHangover: OnStartCommand : 1
 D SushiHangover: 0 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 1 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 2 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 3 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 4 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 5 : 7
 D SushiHangover: OnReceive
 D SushiHangover: OnStartCommand : 1
 D SushiHangover: 6 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 7 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 8 : 6
 D SushiHangover: OnReceive
 D SushiHangover: OnStartCommand : 1
 D SushiHangover: 9 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 10 : 6
 D SushiHangover: OnReceive
 D SushiHangover: OnStartCommand : 1
 D SushiHangover: 11 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 12 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 13 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 14 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 15 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 16 : 7
 D SushiHangover: 17 : 6
 D SushiHangover: 18 : 7
```

Comment: I would never have thought that the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` will cause my Service to be killed when your service receives the `Intent.ActionBootCompleted`. But after a lot of research, I have found that my Location Service would require to be run on the main thread in order to get the GPS data. 

What is the alternative of `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to use in the Android Project ?

Comment: I have edited my code by adding a part of the code of the Location Service. Please advise what is the correct alternative to run this code on a main thread.

Comment: @ExpertGenie `RunOnUiThread` is the Android way to place an action on the UI Thread handler, but since you are starting your service on device boot, you do not have a UI context. FYI: You do not need a UI thread to use a Android.Location based listener (or for Google Location Services API).

Comment: But according to what you have stated, I cannot use the `RunOnUiThread` either since I am starting my service on device boot. And this `RinOnUiThread` will kill my service. But my code requires to be run on the UI thread. See the code in https://pastebin.com/m0KAG3kz 

What if I call the method in the StartCommand before the ServiceThread?

Comment: @ExpertGenie You are still using Xamarin.Forms code (`Forms.Context`) and that would be the `context` of an `Activity` (the one that hosts your `Xamarin.Forms` pages) and thus not available at device boot time (again you have no UI). You can access the `ApplicationContext` (Android Application context) in the `Service`, just pass it to your LocationService so you can call `GetSystemService`. (FYI: Remove any `using` statements that refer to Forms in those files so you can find any other areas that you need to correct)

Comment: Man.. You are the the genius ! :) 
So using the `ApplicationContext`, I will not have to call the LocationService in the `RunOnUIThread` ? and the service will not be killed on device boot? Please confirm. 
I'd never thought of this if you were not here. Thanks a tons.

Comment: @ExpertGenie Correct. Once you update the code, re-test/deploy with a debug session to ensure you did not miss anything. Then use `adb` to do a boot broadcast (I would recommend using some `Log.Debug` statements in your Service methods, etc.. so you can monitor `logcat` to determine that the service is starting, your location services start firing updates, etc...)